# How to get image bytes from telegram message using Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to locate bytes of image contained in the message I'm downloading from telegram channels I'm following. However, I keep getting errors that MessageMediaPhoto does not have attribute bytes. Below is the relevant snipped of code:

```
  if event.photo:
            id = event.message.to_id
            chat_username = client.get_entity(id)
            usr = chat_username.username
            image_base = event.message.media
            image_bytes = image_base.photo.bytes
            message = event.message.id
            url = ("https://t.me/" + str(usr) + "/" + str(message))
            print(url)
            print(image_bytes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
photo_1 = Image.open(photo)
image_buf = BytesIO()
photo_1.save(image_buf, format="JPEG")
image = image_buf.getvalue()
```

Comment: What is the variable photo above? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

you have to download the image first using the `download_media` method first in order to do that. a simple Message object does not have that information.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `BytesIO` from python's `io` library.

```py
from io import BytesIO

image_bytes = BytesIO()
event.message.download_media(image_bytes)
```

Then, we get the image bytes of the message in `image_bytes`.